# Qt5 mouseEntered / mouseExited signal?

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent

Is there a mouseEntered / mouseExited signal in Qt? (Equivalent to mouseEntered / mouseExited from Java) I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I think there is. Please take a look at `QHoverEvent` class.

Comment: Check [QHover](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhoverevent.html)

Comment: ...or [`enterEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and [`leaveEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent).

Comment: There's no such signal. If you can subclass, override [`enterEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and [`leaveEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent), otherwise use an event filter.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to subclass your widget and install an `eventFilter` onto it.

```
class MyButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__()
        self.show()

        self.installEventFilter(self)       //Install event filter on widget

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):       //Define eventFilter method
        if event.type() == Event.Enter:
            print(“Mouse is hovering over button”)
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            print(“Mouse has left the button”) 
        return False
```